# The "superhuman speed" special effect in movies and television

Tags: history-of, powers, trope

What's the earliest example of a character exhibiting "superhuman" speed in either film or television (doesn't have to be Hollywood, if the earliest example is foreign, very interested in hearing of it)? There may be artificial blurring, fast/slow-motion filming, and silly sound effects.

A few examples:

- The vampires in HBO's True Blood
- Quicksilver from the latest X-Men film
- The Flash

Comment: "Trip to the Moon" didn't use special effects like those in the question.  Earliest I can think of is the Road Runner cartoons 1949.

Comment: i was thinking about the road runner too.

Comment: In terms of live-action, the Six Million Dollar Man (starting in 1973) used a combination of slow-motion and a very famous "sha-na-na-na" sound effect to indicate that he was moving incredibly fast. It's gone on to be a bit of a trope, and has been parodied many times.

Comment: I'm tempted to vote as "off topic". It seems like you're asking about the use of the 'motion-blur' effect (in film) rather than about science fiction or fantasy/

Comment: @Chenmunka - there's also some shots of Superman zipping around the screen with motion-blur and whooshing sound effects (though no shots of super-speed from his point of view) in [this old Superman cartoon](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sjdnCC6n4xk) from 1941. You might be able to find it in some older Popeye cartoons after he gets energized by spinach, too.

Comment: @Richard This question might be a good fit for Movies/TV SE for that reason, but it fits here too because OP isn't just asking about motion blur, he's asking about the wide range of effects used to represent super-speed, which is by its nature a sci-fi/fantasy trope.  It's a "behind the scenes" question, not in-universe, but so are [all of these](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genre-trope).  Definitely not off-topic.

Comment: A coworker and I had a conversation today about photography and cinematography, and how this particular special effect and sound effect just aren't realistic even if someone could move that fast. I started to wonder why so many different franchises use such similar effects... trying to determine if it is an actual trope, or just coincidence. Wondering what the originator is, so I can research whether it was actually copied from one movie to the next.

Comment: I agree with @Richard but also Nerrolken. It's definitely skirting the line but I guess we'll leave it here with a slight edit to the question.

Comment: Mike Jittlov's original short film, "Wizard of Speed and Time" (1979) demonstrated a groundbreaking (for its time) mix of live action and stop motion. It was very well received when shown at Noreascon II, the 1980 Worldcon [World Science Fiction Convention].

Comment: https://youtu.be/GoLhLn9hVkE if you want to see the original short.

Answer (score 5):

The original Star Trek "Wink of an Eye" (broadcast in November 1968) had a race that was sped up tremendously.

They sounded like mosquitoes and could not be seen when they moved about.